# Do functions as parameters have to be passed by value?

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand how functions (mainly lambda expressions) as function parameters exactly work. So why are for example comparison functions in the standard library passed by value and not by `const&`?

Comment: In particular, the accepted answer provides an excellent explanation of a rather obscure reason of why function objects should be passed by value.

Comment: Does this also apply for functions with acutal arguments? And do I understand correctly that ```const&``` should also work, but is less performant?

Comment: Yes and yes: the same reasoning applies regardless of the number of arguments the function object takes, and your understanding about `const&` is correct. While you are at that page, consider looking at Ben Voigt's concise answer, it's a nice option to keep in mind.

Comment: The marked answer only talks about `std::function`. If you pass a function by having a templated function, it fits more to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65562986/c-best-practice-pass-use-only-not-stored-lambda-argument-to-function-by-con/65563714#65563714

Answer (score 1):

Functors can have state that they modify.  If you make the functor `const` then it can't modify that state.

Comment: how about predicates to standard algorithms? [Unless otherwise specified, algorithms that take function objects as arguments can copy those function objects freely](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#10.sentence-1), hence a predicate that relies on modfiying internal state yields unpredicable results. Why make a copy in the first place? (or is my "hence" a false premise?)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 It very well may give unpredictable results.  That said, you still want to pass by value since otherwise you wouldn't be able to pass a `std::mt19937` to `std::generate` to create a range of random values.